# running a batch file through java program

Tags: java, runtime

I want to run a batch file through java program. The batch file itself runs a exe file with some filename as arguments. I tried this by creating a C program and running that exe through java. Is there any other way to run a batch file which itself runs a exe through java. Thanks in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run a batch file from my Java Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class CallingBatch {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
run.exec("cmd start /c C:/batfile.bat");
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("FINISHED");
}
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Runtime.exec`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) and pass it `cmd /c /path/to/your/batch/script`.

As of Java 1.5, you can also use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

```
 Process p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "/path/to/batch/file").start();
```

The API docs for `ProcessBuilder` details a more complex setup with working directories and such.

Answer (score 1):

To start with playing with the batch file you have to take some time to learn `PROCESSBUILDER` and Runtime classes.

Program:

```
class RunBatch
{
    public static void main(String[] arg){

        Runtime runtime = null;
        try{
            runtime.getRuntime.exec("CMD START /C D:/myBatchFile.bat");   
        }
        catch(RuntimeException e){ 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My preferred method of starting any process from within java is to use [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)