# running build.xml from java program

Tags: java, ant

i am trying to run ant script from java program.what is the procedure to execute the program
How to run build.xml from java program?

here is how iam trying to implement

```
Process proc = rt.exec("ant -buildfile D:ant\\trail");
```

regards,
techie

Comment: If you have eclipse, then why call it from java?

Comment: actually, i want to create excutable jarfile which on double click will run the antscript

Comment: why don't you just create a simple batch file for that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start ant.bat");`
taken from [How do I run a batch file from my Java Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application)

Comment: but we have to give build.xml file? then from where we have to give

Comment: Have you tried `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start ant.bat  -buildfile D:ant\\trail");` But as you describe you problem I would suggest a simple runAnt.bat

Comment: this is what i get Buildfile: D:ant\trail does not exist!
Build failed

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start ant.bat -buildfile D:\\ant\\trail");` don't forget the \ after the drive letter

Comment: The other thing, how would this cmd window close automatically after running the ant command..

Comment: as iam doing in eclipse, how can i give build.xml path present in my source directory itself

Answer (score 5):

Check here [Execute Ant From Your Application](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/07/24/antauto.html?page=1)
 and look at this example:

```
      Project project = new Project();
      project.init();
      DefaultLogger logger = new DefaultLogger();
      logger.setMessageOutputLevel(Project.MSG_INFO);
      logger.setErrorPrintStream(System.err);
      logger.setOutputPrintStream(System.out);
      project.addBuildListener(logger);

      File buildFile = new File("buildhtml.xml");
      ProjectHelper.configureProject(project, buildFile);
      project.setProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
      project.setProperty("item", "ant");
      project.setProperty("inputdir", "src/items/ant");
      project.setProperty("outputdir", "build/items/ant");
      project.setProperty("graphics.prefix", "../../");
      try {
         project.executeTarget("checkifuptodate");
      } catch(Exception e) {System.err.println(e.getMessage());}
      // rest of program goes here
```

It is a better solution than calling `Runtime.exec`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to start a windows executable separately, it'd be a more robust and flexible solution to use the Ant API.  Docs are included with ant itself, they are [not online](http://ant.apache.org/manual/api/index.html)...