# Operative System Total Ram Size

Tags: java, windows, ram

im trying to get the total ram size of windows os using **JAVA** but i got nothing. I was looking for any alternative of [GlobalMemoryStatusEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) too, but nothing again...

If anyone can help me please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, i need the system RAM, not the Java Machine RAM

Comment: @Fakefo0r look at the title of the article. It's about finding the system RAM. Which you can't with pure Java code.

Comment: Call `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` with `JNI`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible solution to my problem. Using windows command line you can get much useful information so just needed some code that could send commands to CMD.EXE and receive the response. The solutión was in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637290/get-command-prompt-output-to-string-in-java)

Using the command **"wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory"** i get:

```
TotalPhysicalMemory
6352433152
```

I only will need tu parse the response!

Thanks for atention.