# Calling CMD command through JAVA

Tags: java, cmd, taskkill

I have a method called taskkill() written in java. I want to implement the cmd command taskkill in the selected field (as shown). I don't know how to apply this command in java. Please help.

```
    public static Timer taskkill() {

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {             
      // TO APPLY CMD COMMAND [ TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE ne File1" /FI "WINDOWTITLE ne File2" ]
    }
};

Timer timer = new Timer("MyTimer");  //create a new Timer

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 30, 10000);  //this line starts the timer at the same time its executed

return timer;
```

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().execute()` may be what you're after.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TASKKILL command implementation using JAVA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24545819/taskkill-command-implementation-using-java)

Comment: But how should I use "Runtime.getRuntime().execute()" to implement taskkill command. Please wrap the taskkill command in the said function. I shall be really thankful to you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29) which allows you to run arbitrary programs from the JVM (modulus relevant permissions of course).

Cheers,