# Concise way of capturing the output of process in Java

Tags: java

To capture the output of process in Groovy I use the following:

```
"command".execute().text
```

I want to do the same in Java, but all responses I found contain a lot of boilerplate code involving loops, `BufferedReader`, `Scanner`, etc.:

- [Get Command Prompt Output to String In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637290/get-command-prompt-output-to-string-in-java)
- [How to run Windows commands in JAVA and return the result text as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963413/how-to-run-windows-commands-in-java-and-return-the-result-text-as-a-string)
- [java runtime.getruntime() getting output from executing a command line program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711084/java-runtime-getruntime-getting-output-from-executing-a-command-line-program)

Can I do the same thing within 1-2 lines of code? Maybe Guava or Apache have something to make life simpler?

Comment: Java is roughly synonymous with boilerplate code. In this case, there might be a lib (probably is) that will help, but much of Java is going to be boilerplate. I'm fairly sure you can do this in like . . . 5-10 lines though.

Comment: There is [Apache Commons Exec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/), I've never used it, so I don't know how good it is. It is a problem that comes up so infrequently that it's probably not worth it. I wrote my own ten-line process runner a few years ago, and I've been happily using it since.

Comment: if you have access to the groovy jar in your project, you can call getText(<process>) and have the same result

Comment: @CollinD the thing here is that I need to use it once in one unit test, so these 5-10 lines would be more than a test itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've managed to come up with the following two-liner:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("command")'
String output = IOUtils.toString(process.getInputStream());
```

Comment: if your process use stderr, you can block

Comment: @JérémieB can you explain that scenario? What do you mean by "you can block"?

Comment: Did you mean process.getOutputStream() ? your question was how to capture output.

Comment: if the process write to the error stream, and you don't read it, then the standard buffer will be full, and the process will block waiting some space in this buffer. as a consequence, your code will block, waiting the process to be terminated. the streams of the process must be "pumped".

Comment: Did you exactly look at toString() on IOUtils, toString() takes InputStream, I don't see any method that takes "OutputStream"

Comment: Process.getInputStream() return the output of the process

Comment: @JeremieB interesting indeed. But then majority of other SO answers have the same but anyway.

Comment: This is a bad idea. As @JérémieB points out, if the process writes to stderr your program will block. A lot of procsses write to stderr when they encounter errors. Your program will simply block in those cases and you have no idea what has happened.

Comment: @JonTirsen you are right. Can you propose the correct solution? I'll accept it when proved to work.