# Running msys.bat using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java

I am attempting to run msys.bat in java using ProcessBuilder. When I run the .bat file with my program, the following error occurred: "Cannot find the rxvt.exe or sh.exe binary -- aborting. Press any key to continue . . ."

Here is the code,

```
    ProcessBuilder Msys = new ProcessBuilder("C:/msys/1.0/msys.bat", "/C", "find \"C:/Users/Dan G/Desktop/hello.elf\"");

    Process p = Msys.start();

    String line;
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    r.close();
```

The goal is to compile some C projects of mine. The command up there is just to test for a result, not what I want to accomplish.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/616014/617996)... Possible duplicate...

Comment: @Prim: yep you're right: this is a probable duplicate of [How do I run a batch file from my Java Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application) and probably should be closed.

Comment: Sorry, I was searching for a bit and never found a working answer. That link does help a bit in combination with what Hovercraft had posted below. Just needed cmd.exe /c "start" msys.bat. Thanks both of you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.bat files can't run on their own and are called on the Windows command processor. So don't forget to load the Windows command processor too, cmd.exe before your bat file.

```
ProcessBuilder Msys = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "C:/msys/1.0/msys.bat", 
       "/C", "find \"C:/Users/Dan G/Desktop/hello.elf\"");
```

**Edit**
Please check out this useful article for tips and traps that occur with this process: [when runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). The code in the article is a bit dated, but the concepts are just as germane today as they were then. It is highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't known that about batch files.

Comment: @DanGerendasy: you're quite welcome. Please see warnings though of running outside processes in Java per the link in an edit to my answer.