# Cannot run program "npm" in directory

Tags: node.js, maven, gruntjs

When i am traversing the to `src/main/app/` folder structure where i  have the `package.JSON` & gruntfile, i am able to run `npm install` and `grunt` command. But when i am trying to run the `mvn jetty:run` and a property file in the root folder of the project when POM file is present, it is throwing error that it cannot run `npm install` in the folder structure `src/main/app/`.

This is the exact error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (n
pminstall) on project my-abc-web: Command execution failed. Cannot
 run program "npm" (in directory "C:\Users\Achyut_J01\Documents\GitHub\infras\my-abc\my-abc-web\src\main\app"): CreatePro
cess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]
```

It's a Windows Machine.

Comment: The error mentions not being able to run `npm`, and you claim to be able to run `npm-install`. Those aren't the same.

Comment: yes, when i am running npm install , i am geting the following output - npm WARN package.json webapp@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json webapp@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json webapp@0.0.0 No README data

Comment: Are you running `npm install` or `npm-install`?

Comment: When i only run npm the it gives me the npm usage

Comment: Do you run `npm` and `mvn` in the exact same command prompt?

Comment: yes i run both mvn and npm in same propmt & i am using npm install(without hyphen)

Comment: And what if you give the full `npm` path, like `c:\..\npm` to your `maven-exec-plugin` ?

Comment: @krampstudio If you see the error message it is executing the complete path starting from c:\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evidently you are on a Windows system.  npm is a batch file and not an executable.  There are [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12603300/254643) running a batch file from maven exec plugin.  You may want to explore the workaround suggested in the link, like

- deconstruct the .bat script into its actual commands
- use cmd.exe and pass node as parameter - [refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12604890/254643).

Comment: @Raghuram How would I make npm install OS **independent** in the pom.xml? I'm working on a project where we need to be able to build on both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 16):

I used this workaround to have a cross-platform Maven build : declare the npm executable name as a Maven variable, and use Maven filters to modify this executable name when running on Windows.

It can work the same for Grunt, Bower etc.

**This workaround is not necessary any more if you use exec-maven-plugin >=1.6.0** (thanks Manmay for the information in the comments): it was a bug of this plugin (see https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/issues/42), that has been fixed in 1.6.0 (see https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/pull/46)

```
<properties>
    <npm.executable>npm</npm.executable>
</properties>

(...)

<build>
    <plugins>
        (...)
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>exec-npm</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>${npm.executable}</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>install</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        (...)
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>platform-windows</id>
        <activation>
            <os>
                <family>windows</family>
            </os>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <!-- Override the executable names for Windows -->
            <npm.executable>npm.cmd</npm.executable>
            <grunt.executable>grunt.cmd</grunt.executable>
            <bower.executable>bower.cmd</bower.executable>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: That's a great solution. I used to have two separated plugin calls in each profile (had one for Windows and one for Unix). This really has reduced lines in my pom file. Thank you!

Comment: Best solution ever! Congrats!

Comment: You dont have to change anything if you are using plugin version 1.6.0

Comment: @Manmay Your comment should be marked as answer. After hours of googling, there's nothing to read apart from comments. Finally found your comments and it worked magically.

Answer (score 10):

In Windows Platform, use **npm.cmd** to replace **npm**

Comment: This would make the build break on non Windows OSes, how could this be solved to become OS **independent**?

Comment: if you use maven, just choose to a plugin, such as [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin). see [this](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#running-npm). It will choose command depends on your OS [details](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin#frontend-maven-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

See the link for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48184182/4282901

In the directory where node is installed rename the batch file so that the existing npm.cmd file is picked. See screenshot below: 
[image: rename npm so that npm.cmd is picked by default in windows]

This method is preferable if you build the projects targeting linux and windows both. Moreover, also if the no. of pom files is also large.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the directory in which node and npm are installed is added to your PATH variable. If it is, you shouldn't have to change your .pom files at all. This is tested on 1.6.0, so you may have to use the workaround mentioned by @Mossroy if you use 1.5.0.

Answer (score -2):

### npm is a shell script.

renaming it npm.sh on windows worked for me.

Windows searched 'npm' and did not find,
it then tries npm.bat which exists

Comment: I'ts more likely that the paths are messed up. I wouldn't recommend renaming files of a node (or any other) installed tool.