# CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application -> [Help 1]

Tags: angularjs, node.js, maven

When running exec-npm-update in maven , I am getting the following error 
CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application -> [Help 1]

Below is the snippet from pom file.

```
<execution>
                <id>exec-npm-update</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                  <workingDirectory>${uiResourcesDir}</workingDirectory>
                  <executable>npm</executable>
                  <arguments>
                    <argument>update</argument>
                  </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                  <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This problem happened because the angular version I am using is 1.5.

changing the executable from npm to npm.cmd solved the problem!

```
<execution>
                <id>exec-npm-update</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                  <workingDirectory>${uiResourcesDir}</workingDirectory>
                  <executable>npm.cmd</executable>
                  <arguments>
                    <argument>update</argument>
                  </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                  <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you like to run the shell or command prompt commands irrespective of environment. I am talking about npm.cmd (windows), npm.sh (linux) parts.

**Downgrade the maven-exec-plugin to Version 1.4.0** so that you can just mention (For e.g.)

```
<executable>npm</executable>
<executable>ng</executable>
```

Comment: I think this one is a better solution, as it works for both, Windows & Linux and you can use it to build in pipelines. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue, as answered you need to provide npm.cmd instead just npm

Comment: You can use maven profiles if your POM.xml has to be OS agnostic... See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39407412/704681