# Exec-NPM-Install is throwing error for local nexus

Tags: node.js, npm

I had been trying to build an app on a Windows 10 OS and I've been given code that I have to run "mvn install" on to build the app. When I do this, I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (exec-npm-install) on
>   project filter: Command execution failed. Process exited with an
>   error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]

```
POM:
<build>
    <finalName>filter</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>exec-npm-install</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>npm</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>--loglevel</argument>
                            <argument>error</argument>
                            <argument>install</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
```

Stack overflow link i checked, didn't helped:
[Maven failed to execute goal - cannot run program npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48156538/maven-failed-to-execute-goal-cannot-run-program-npm/48184182)

Can anyone let me know what might be the resolution on this?