# Maven exec plugin build SUCCESS even if executable fails on Windows

Tags: java, maven, exec-maven-plugin

I have a maven project in which I execute a windows `.bat` file using maven exec plugin. The problem is that, even if the bat execution fails (i.e. exit code is -1) the build of the project is SUCCESS.

Here is my defined plugin:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.0</version>
   <executions>
       <execution>
           <phase>compile</phase>
           <goals>
               <goal>exec</goal>
           </goals>
           <configuration>
               <executable>run.bat</executable>
           </configuration>
       </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

Please note that the same behave as expected if I execute it on Unix (i.e. execute .sh file and build fails).

Answer (score 1):

See [noahlz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12603300/1744774) to the question [Launching a windows batch script using Maven exec plugin ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597879/launching-a-windows-batch-script-using-maven-exec-plugin-blocks-the-build-even-t):

> *Windows Batch Files are not executable. They are scripts that are run by the `cmd` executable.*
>
> *... the short version is: this isn't a problem with "Maven," it's a problem with the platform-dependent nature of executing an `exec()` command.*

If a command in your `run.bat` sets `%ERRORLEVEL%` this is set in the executing CMD but not passed to CMD's caller, i.e. the Maven Exec plugin. Exiting your `run.bat` with [`EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%`](http://ss64.com/nt/exit.html) explicitely should do the trick.

Comment: Gerold Broser, thanks for pointing to noahlz answer (actually I already found it) Unfortunatelly, exiting with %ERRORLEVEL% doesn't help. So I followed noahlz' advise to deconstruct the .bat script into its actual commands and launch it directly from the exec plugin.