# java api to run windows batch programs?

Tags: java, windows, api, class, batch-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I run a batch file from my Java Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application)

Are there Java classes to run Windows batch files?  For example, start the batch files and receive the results of the batch runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) is a good way to go. Solves several problems you'd encounter if using pure ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec.

From the project description:

> Executing external processes from Java is a well-known problem area. It is inheriently platform dependent and requires the developer to know and test for platform specific behaviors, for example using cmd.exe on Windows or limited buffer sizes causing deadlocks. The JRE support for this is very limited, albeit better with the new Java SE 1.5 ProcessBuilder class.

Answer (score 0):

The usual [`ProcessBuilder` stuff](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) works with batch files, as does [`Runtime#exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29). The command you're executing is `cmd.exe`, the batch file name is an argument to it. I believe the argument sequence is `cmd.exe`, `/c`, `batch_file_name`. *(Edit: Yup, and in fact, I found a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application) that this question duplicates on SO where that's in the answer.)*

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start batFileName.bat");` should work.
But to read the output from java process, remove `start` from the above comman.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to my knowledge, RunTime classe can. And ofcourse, ProcessBuilder also like that. I have run number of batch files using Java. Following is the google search result. It has links which are equally important

[GOOGLE RESULT](http://www.google.lk/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=how+to+run+batch+files+using+java+and+get+its+results&oq=how+to+run+batch+files+using+java+and+get+its+results&gs_l=hp.3..33i21.142.13899.0.14103.53.40.0.4.4.5.2693.29898.3-2j3j10j5j5j5j2.32.0...0.0...1c.1.r6MD9zhEFcE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=5babac200cee15c&bpcl=35466521&biw=1366&bih=643)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use native Java and no 3rd party packages then try this using `Runtime` and `Process`. I'm not the best Java coder in the world but this should get what you want. It might need some modification to add a loop for reading everything from the input stream.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process batch = rt.exec("test.bat");

            batch.waitFor();

            //exitValue() contains the ERRORLEVEL from batch file
            System.out.println(batch.exitValue());

            //getInputStream will get all output from stdout
            //getErrorStream will get all error output from stderr
            InputStream inStream = batch.getInputStream();
            byte[] text = new byte[inStream.available()];
            inStream.read(text);

            System.out.println(new String(text));
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```