# Run .bat with JUnit4

Tags: java, batch-file, junit, junit4

I need to test my java application with JUnit4 but my application runs with a .bat file.
I would need to run this .bat file in the @Before method but I don't know how can I do it.

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start filename.bat");
```

should do the magic ;)

For more Information see: [Java docs: Runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html)