# How to double click or single click the BAT file using Java or java script which is available in the specified path

Tags: java, process

Scenario was i created a BAT file and stored in C drive. I need to write a code for double click or single click using Java.

This is what I tried in Java but it did not work:

```
try {
    String path = "cmd /c start C:\\KeyManager_Stop.bat";
    Runtime rn = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr = rn.exec(path);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The batch file contains:

```
cd c:\test\test.cmd stop
```

Comment: Why not simply execute it?

Comment: Use Runtime.exec(<your_batch_file)

Comment: Inside that Bat files i given some internal command to start the Process. If we double clicked that it automatically start the process

Comment: Hi Sandiip, I have used the Runtime.exec also is not working.

Comment: First, Java and JavaScript are NOT the same thing. They are not even close. The only real relation is the name. Second, can you post your script so we can see what is going wrong with Runtime.exec?

Comment: if you need just execute the bat file then your question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application

Comment: This script written for java try {
    String path="cmd /c start C:\\KeyManager_Stop.bat";
    Runtime rn=Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process pr=rn.exec(path);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();  
         }

Comment: In batch File I written the code "cd c:\test\test.cmd stop".

Comment: @SaravanakumarMarudhachalam Did you get an error message? Did you try to consume the process output stream? etc.

Comment: So basically you are trying to run one batch file which in turn will close another batch. What is test.cmd?

Comment: Hi Assylias,No error Message

Comment: Hi sandiip, Test.cmd is project file if we given "test.cmd start" it will start the application or "test.cmd stop" it will stop the application

Comment: So you want a batch file to stop your application?

Comment: Yes Sandiip So any Possible code?

Comment: Your path looks fine but not sure if \\ has to do something with it. Try like below:
Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[]{"cmd", "/C", "KeyManager_Stop.bat"}, null, new File("D://"));