# Run a autohotkey (ahk) script from java

Tags: java, windows, autohotkey

is there a way to run a script with parameters from java?
Not an executable file, but an AutoHotKey script.

I tried this, but since it is not a valid executable file it doesn't work.

Control class :

```
package org.bsep.acp;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * This class allow you to send string to your
 * computer as keystrokes.
 * 
 * escape car is '
 * special char are {space}, {Enter}, {F1}, {F2}, etc
 * 
 * @author Eildosa
 */
public class StringSender {

    Runtime runtime;
    private final static String AHK_BRIDGE = "C:\\perso\\WorkspaceScripts\\skyrimTools\\src\\org\\bsep\\acp\\ahkBridge.ahk";

    public StringSender() {
        runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    }

    public void sendString(String data) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        runtime.exec(new String[] { AHK_BRIDGE, data} );
        Thread.currentThread();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

}
```

Test :

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
runtime.exec(NOTEPAD);
Thread.currentThread();
Thread.sleep(4000);
StringSender stringSender = new StringSender();
stringSender.sendString("Writing from java through AHK.");
```

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\perso\WorkspaceScripts\skyrimTools\src\org\bsep\acp\ahkBridge.ahk": CreateProcess error=193, %1 n?est pas une application Win32 valid
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
    at org.bsep.acp.StringSender.sendString(StringSender.java:25)
    at org.bsep.acp.VariousTests.ahkBridgeTester(VariousTests.java:23)
    at org.bsep.acp.VariousTests.main(VariousTests.java:13)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 n?est pas une application Win32 valid
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:376)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 5 more
```

Translation : this is not a valid win32 application.

Thanks.

Comment: What do `AHK_BRIDGE` and `data` contain? Please post a sufficient amount of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since raw AHK scripts aren't executable, you can either compile your script and execute it directly or pass the path of your script as an argument to `AutoHotkey.exe` (usually located in `C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\`). Regarding the second option, your code could look like this:

```
public void sendString(String data) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String ahkPath = "C:\\Program Files\\AutoHotkey\\AutoHotkey.exe";
    String scriptPath = "C:\\Users\\MCL\\test.ahk";
    runtime.exec(new String[] { ahkPath, scriptPath, data} );
    Thread.currentThread();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

AutoHotkey will pass on each argument to the script, starting with the second (in this case: `data`).

Comment: @Eildosa Depending on what you're doing, you could also consider incorporating `AutoHotkey.dll` as described [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EX0iT0NTTjw).

Answer (score 0):

You could bring another middle man into it, ie a bat script that launches ahk. Which could be launched through exec, here is an so post on launching bat

[How do I run a batch file from my Java Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application)

First try command line invocation of ahk passing the script but I'm not sure that will work, worth a try though

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `java.awt.Desktop` class to *open* the script if AHK files are (correctly) associated with AutoHotKey, and if `Desktop` is supported (check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html) for details).

```
import java.awt.Desktop;

// . . .

    private final static String AHK_BRIDGE = "C:\\perso\\WorkspaceScripts\\skyrimTools\\src\\org\\bsep\\acp\\ahkBridge.ahk";

// . . . 

    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(AHK_BRIDGE));
    } else {
        // error message, Exception, or Runtime solution from other answers
    }
```