# Run batch file using Runtime.exec without using cmd.exe

Tags: java, linux, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am running a Java application that executes a script. The relevant code is

```
    String command [] = new String [2];
    command[0] =  "customSearch";
    command[1] =  query;    

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

This code runs on Linux because I placed a script called `customSearch` in the `/usr/bin` directory. In a similar way, I created a batch file in Windows called `customSearch.bat` and made sure it is on the `PATH`. However, this Java code will not work on Windows because "Batch files alone are not executable" as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application) thread mentions.

So to get it to work on Windows, I would have to say

```
    command[0] =  "cmd /c start customSearch";
```

However, I do not want to do this because this won't work on Linux. How can I run the batch file on Windows without changing `command[0]` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can add a check if the OS is Windows and then execute a custom-windows-batch-runner-snippet.

For example, I created a simple `test.bat` file with a `netstat` command within:

```
netstat
```

Here's how I executed it by a Java snippet:

```
String os = System.getProperty("os.name");
if (os.toLowerCase().indexOf("win") >= 0) {
    command = new String[1];
    command[0] = "test.bat";  

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = is.readLine()) != null) {
       System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

This is the result in the console:

```
D:\workspace\SO>netstat

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:19872        hp:49266               ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49169        hp:49170               ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49170        hp:49169               ESTABLISHED'
....
```

Even better, you can wrap every OS-specific command-executing snippets with `if` statements.

Comment: How do I include customSearch in this? Is it part of "query"?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. :)

Comment: This is weird. Now, I get "Cannot run program "cmd /c start""

Comment: I will revisit this soon. Gotta go! Thanks for the help.