# Runtime.exec() without fork in java

Tags: java

How can i invoke batch file without fork in java?
I use NSSM command-line interface to install my product as windows service. I always use Runtime.exec() to operate with command-line. I bypass bytes from new process's streams and periodically check for it finish job. I wonder, if there is easy way to use command line? I don't need forked process, is there a way not to use it? I want just call some exec("command") function, which acts as simple procedure.

Comment: What complex is working with `Runtime.exec()`. And what would you like to achieve? It is very straight forward way to execute external processes from java using `exec()`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do the equivalent of Unix / Linux `exec()` syscall or the Posix shell `exec` command ... without forking ... in Java.  It is not supported by the standard Java class libraries.

It *may* be possible to write a native code method to call the OS-provided native libraries to do an `exec` or equivalent.  However, this could behave in unexpected ways (e.g. no shutdown hooks) and would definitely be non-portable.  And in the case of Windows, I don't think it is possible to do the equivalent of UNIX `exec` without `fork`: source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93exec).

However, you can *easily* run a batch file from Java:

- [How do I run a batch file from my Java Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application)

But I don't understand the point of doing an `exec` to run a batch file instead of the normal `fork` / `exec` ... which is what `Runtime.exec()` does under the covers.  Perhaps if you explained, we could understand why you *need* to do it, and offer a suggestion.