# Start an external process while stopping current process

Tags: java

Not sure what's the right word for this or if this is possible.
I would like to start an external process and stop the current process in the same terminal window.
(I would like to avoid piping I/O streams for the child process.)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ip = chooseFromCommandLine();
    String cmdLine = "ping " + ip;

    // launch cmdLine in the same terminal and exit this process
}
```

Essentially to create a "launcher"-type application but for the terminal.

Comment: Simple Library to make the process of executing system commands through java a simple task. The library is thread-safe, can be used to execute multiple commands asynchronously.` https://github.com/mhashim6/System-Command-Executor `

Comment: @HariKishore - That actually does something a bit different.  The current process is not **replaced**.

Comment: Please don't re-tag the question to change the topic matter.  If you want to ask about how to do this in C or shell or something else, **ask a new question**.   (And search for existing Q&A's first.)

Comment: it was always about execing, java is just a tool (the wrong tool in this instance)

Comment: I wanted to know how to do it easily, I don't want to fight with the language, the JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UNIX / Linux / POSIX, the terminology for this is "execing" the application.  The current executing process is *replaced* with a new application.

Unfortunately, you can't do that in pure Java.  You may be able to do it from native code that you call from Java.

Java's `Runtime.exec(...)` etcetera methods do the equivalent of a POSIX `fork` followed by `exec` in the child process.  In other words, the parent process (i.e. the JVM) keeps running.

Comment: I just noticed I answered a similar question 6 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658894.

Comment: java is not a strong requirement for me, is it possible to exec in a "portable" way? (so it works on at least linux and windows.) is it just an exec call in C?

Comment: Ask a new question.  This question was asked and answered about Java