# How to run a specific java file present in eclipse using batch file?

Tags: java

I have to create a batch file such that it should call a specific java file present in eclipse.

Comment: It should call or Run ?

Comment: in batch file it should call specified file present in src folder, after that i need to write a java program which automatically trigger batch file thanks in advance

Comment: Why dont you start the "java file" from Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, your java file is in path:

`D:/WorkDir/Java/Filename.java`

Then your bat file (say `abc.bat`) should be,

```
d:
cd WorkDir/Java
java Filename
```

Below is an example, where you have commands to set java class path and include additional jar files and pass arguments to Filename.java

```
set classpath=%classpath%;c:\MY APPS\lib\log4j.jar;
d:
cd WorkDir/Java
java Filename arg1 arg2 arg3 etc
```

To call the bat file from java, you need to use runtime.exec as below and in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application).

```
Runtime rn=Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr=rn.exec(path);
```

Comment: In the batch file you can use `pushd %~dp0` to change dir to current directory. Otherwise it will be Eclipse's working directory.

Comment: @Stefan: Bat files are necessary for scheduler type of applications. We use in our environment. For normal cases, as you recommend, we can start the java file from java itself.

Comment: @user3427658: That is just a sample. Say you want to add log4j.jar to your class path, then you can add such jars in your classpath with the command mentioned.

Comment: acutally i received src folder frm my mentor, its der in my document folder.i tried to create a batch file like this

Comment: Ok..so how do you want me to help?

Comment: pushd %DIRNAME%..
pushd %DIRNAME%..
pushd %DIRNAME%..
set DCM_HOME=%CD%
set PATH=%PATH%;
set CW_CLASSPATH="%DCM_HOME%Users\sjuttu\Documents\My Received Files\src\lib\diffutils-1.2.1.jar;%DCM_HOME%Users\sjuttu\Documents\My Received Files\src\lib\log4j-1.2.16.jar;%DCM_HOME%Users\sjuttu\Documents\My Received Files\src\lib\postgresql-9.3-1101.jdbc41.jar;%DCM_HOME%Users\sjuttu\Documents\My Received Files\src\lib\super-csv-2.2.0.jar;%DCM_HOME%Users\sjuttu\Documents\My Received Files\src\lib\util.jar

Comment: set CW_CMD="%DCM_HOME%Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java" -cp %CW_CLASSPATH% com.brocade.comparator.DatabaseComparator
cmd /c start "Java" %CW_CMD%
pause but i dnt knw wether this code is crt or not, "cmd /c start "java" %CW_CMD%" purpose is what. thanks in advance