# Launch a .bat file from java class:

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm looking for help with my java code. I would like to start running a .bat from java code
someone can help me please, thanks in advance :)

Comment: This question is a total duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start yourbatchfile.bat");
```

Comment: when i try this code : i have an error message : windows cannot find "test.bat" make sure you typed the name correctly ...

Comment: This sounds like you are not using the correct _path_ to your file `test.bat`.  A quick fix would be for you to put the full name of the file, e.g. `C:\\Directory\\Subdirectory\\yourbatchfile.bat`

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start build.bat");
```

refer this : [How do I run a batch file from my Java Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application)

Comment: I know where you've been looking...

Answer (score 0):

Add following code line and it will run the bat `batFile.bat`

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start batFile.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

I always do it like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "build.bat"});
```

Or use the ProcessBuilder class in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

```
File batchFile = new File("build.bat"); //Or wherever your file is
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(batchFile.getAbsolutePath());
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

For more info, look at the JavaDoc link :)