# How to execute command prompt command through java

Tags: java

I am trying to download zip file from `svn` using java but nothing worked out.
Through command prompt it is getting downloaded so i thought of executing command prompt through `java`.
My `java` code is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class aaa {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String command = "svn co --username username --password pass http://interactive/svn/Test_Mariza/trunk/test/seatapps.zip /home/vaishali/aaa/";

    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    // Read the output

    BufferedReader reader =  
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    String line = "";
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.print(line + "\n");
    }

    proc.waitFor();   

}
}
```

The command which i am passing as an argument is executing through terminal but not getting executed through java code.
Can anyone help me out.

Comment: I have replaced your user name with `username ` and your password with `pass` for security purposes. Please revert them back should you wish to show such credentials.

Comment: Yes the same command if i run through terminal then it is getting executed

Comment: I forgot to replace it thanks npinti

Comment: any error you are getting??

Answer (score -2):

To execute a command in Java:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(" Insert command here ");
```

For references:
[How do I run a batch file from my Java Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application)

Comment: That's already what they're doing at they said that part's working.