# Where should i place .bat file to run through java code?

Tags: java, batch-file

I'm trying to run `First.bat` file through java code but I'm getting error(Warning) popup that says

> Windows cannot find First.bat. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.

Can anyone tell me what kind of error is it and where do I exactly place `.bat` file to excute?

```
Process batRun = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start First.bat");
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing `cmd` through java and default location where cmd starts is `C:\Users\Username>`. Put `First.bat` in `C:\Users\Username` or provide absolute path to your `First.bat` like `D:\\MyFolder\\First.bat`

```
Process batRun = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c D:\\MyFolder\\First.bat");
```