# Java - Execute External Windows Applications?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, intellij-idea, executable

I'm unsure how to start an external application (**specifically on *Windows***) through *Java* code. I'm not planning on using this *Java* code for *Mac/Linux*, so let's focus on the *Windows* code.

## What I've Done

I've been researching this question for the last two days, and I still have not found an answer. I easily found the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` method, but the thing is I cannot find information on **launching a Batch (.bat) file from my local workspace in *IntelliJ Idea***.

## What I'm Asking

I would just like to know **how to execute a local Batch file in my workspace** (at a folder like `com.example.batch`) and/or how to execute a (.exe) or (.bat) with the direct file address. (For example the *Defragment and Optimize Drives* (.exe) for *Windows*: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\dfrgui.exe`)

Thanks to all in advance, I've been dying for this answer.

Comment: Have you tried something like the answer for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the essential [Runtime.exec() article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html)?

Page 2 of this article lists a common pitfall: **Runtime.exec() is not a command line**.

.bat files are not executables. They are collections of instructions. Like shell scripts in Linux, you need something to actually execute these instructions.

Your executable in this case is `cmd.exe`, which will take `/C` and `com.example.batch` as its arguments:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/C", "com.example.batch"});
```

As a side note, check out the `ProcessBuilder` class. It's much nicer than `Runtime`. And yes, all the rules in the `Runtime` article apply to `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Great answer. I chose it because you focused on one topic you gave complete detail into. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, you should be using `ProcessBuilder` to execute external programs, for an easier-to-use interface than `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`.

Second, to execute a `.bat` file, all you have to do is execute `cmd.exe` and pass the batch file name in the `/C` option.  Note that when you run a batch file you are starting a DOS cmd processor and telling it to run the batch file instead of reading from the terminal.  Therefore, the batch file must be in a location that is accessible to `cmd.exe`.  Therefore it cannot be inside a jar file containing your Java program.  If it is necessary to distribute it in the jar you will have to copy it to the filesystem somewhere.

Comment: (About second option) Would that allow me to launch .bat from the project workspace?