# Running a file using cmd on windows

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, cmd

> This is my directory.
>   `"C:\JAYAPRAKASH\softwares\ignite\gridgain-web-console-on-premise-2020.02.00".`
>   In this directory i have a file web-console (widows batch file).
>   Now i need to run this file by Java, How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(  The path to the file   );
```