# Running batch file in java

Tags: java

I am trying to run a batch file using java. The batch file in turn runs a python program. So i should wait till the batch file is done and then proceed with my program.

Problems facing:

1. I could not run batch file in background. I am able to run it only via start

   **`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start c://GCTI//IA/QAART//testercheck.bat");`**
2. once the batch file ran, it is not closing automatically.

Batch file

```
"C:\Python27\python.exe" -i "C:\GCTI\IA\QAART\tester\test_monitor.py" -init "C:\GCTI\IA\EpiPhone\Dispatcher6\init\INIT_Designer_QAART_Dispatcher_Chat.PY" -testlist "C:\GCTI\IA\ASR_QAART\dat files\ChatAutomation\chat.dat" 23
```

Can you please help me to run this batch ile in background?

Comment: Hello @AarthiKannan! Welcome to StackOverflow!  Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615948/how-do-i-run-a-batch-file-from-my-java-application

Comment: Hi Martens , I need to run this in my background. But when using start the cmd window is opening which is disturbing the ui automation. So i need to run this bat in background once it is done i should be able to proceed forward.

Comment: what is the problem that you're facing? (It is e.g a error code? or, unexpected behavior - if you try to run it in background?) Edit: the bat file  - (if this is possible in your bat file) - can't it have some exit at the end of it?

Comment: when i manually run this using cmd, the application is running and it is not exiting.

Fatal Error              -   YES

User Error              -     1

All tests                -     1
Skipped                  -     0
Missed                   -     0
Executed                 -     1
  Failed                 -     1
  Passed                 -     0


+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>>>


so where can i mention in bat file to exit?

Comment: can you maybe just try to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("batfile.bat");` ? Just to see if that works, or not.

Comment: try {
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("c://GCTI//IA/QAART//testercheck.bat");
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
   StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
   String line;
   while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
   {
    sb.append(line);
   }
   
   int returnCode=p.waitFor();
   if(returnCode==0)
    System.out.println(sb);
   else
    System.out.println(("Not Successfull"));
  } catch (IOException ex) {
   System.out.println(ex);
  }
This is my program, the application is working but it's getting stuck in waitFor() method

Comment: Hi Aarthi, I wonder if the `-i` makes the Python session to stay open.  The Python help says that `-i` will "inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even if stdin does not appear to be a terminal;".  Experiment to see if you can run Python without `-i`.  Just an idea.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the batch file. You can execute the *Python* program directly from Java code using class [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

```java
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Python27\\python.exe",
                                       "-i",
                                       "C:\\GCTI\\IA\QAART\\tester\\test_monitor.py",
                                       "-init",
                                       "C:\\GCTI\\IA\\EpiPhone\\Dispatcher6\\init\\INIT_Designer_QAART_Dispatcher_Chat.PY",
                                       "-testlist",
                                       "C:\\GCTI\\IA\\ASR_QAART\\dat files\\ChatAutomation\\chat.dat",
                                       "23");
Process p = pb.start();
int result = p.waitFor();
```

Refer to other methods in class `ProcessBuilder` for handling the output of the Python script, for example method [inheritIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--)